# NestJs authorize/validate user owns resource

Tags: nestjs

What is the standard way of validating/authorizing that a user has access to a resource?

For example: a user can PUT `comment/:id` to update a comment, and I want to check if the user is allowed to.

Guards aren't ideal because they run before any validation and I need to access the comment id.

I've also tried a custom Param pipe but I'm struggling to access the request execution context from it to get the user.

Finally I could also just put the logic in the controller.

This seems like a pretty common use case so I was wondering: how does this typically get solved?

Comment: you can create a custom parameter with `createParamDecorator`: https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators to get the user, it is pretty easy

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yeah that's what I've done when I say validate inside the controller: get the user through a parameter decorator and then validate with a service method. In express I'd usually use middleware for this but I guess with Nest this way is the best to take advantage of both parameter validation and the user access. Ideally though I would like to keep validation outside of the controller body if possible.

Answer (score -1):

A common practice is to use `OAuth 2` framework. Each valid user will have associated accesstoken that will be validated in the server before the user is allowed to access resource.

For NestJs Framework, you can checkout the official documentation on how to achieve this. https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization